# Why doesn't glib use private futexes?

Tags: glib, futex

When investigating some performance issues, I finally ended up in gthread-posix.c.
There I found code such as:

```
static void __attribute__((noinline))
g_mutex_lock_slowpath (GMutex *mutex)
{
  /* Set to 2 to indicate contention.  If it was zero before then we
   * just acquired the lock.
   *
   * Otherwise, sleep for as long as the 2 remains...
   */
  while (exchange_acquire (&mutex->i[0], 2) != 0)
    syscall (__NR_futex, &mutex->i[0], (gsize) FUTEX_WAIT, (gsize) 2, NULL);
}
```

I am curious as to why it doesn't use FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE here and it other places. At least on the ARM the non-private futexes are significantly slower, and I was under the impression that glib is for multithreading rather than interprocess communication in shared memory.

Comment: Perhaps bug glibc mailing list re: https://lwn.net/Articles/229668/ ? I imagine it was already discussed....

Answer (score 0):

GLib does now use `FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE`, since March 2015. See [this commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/commit/627a145e16abe92dc5fe94bff6a379a9a1379837) and [the related bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=741442).